# Specializing member template for enum type arguments

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

In the code below, `Foo<T>::setValue` works well for my purposes, except in cases where where `T` is a class enum named `TYPE` e.g. `Bar::TYPE` and `Baz:TYPE`.

Therefore, I'd appreciate help specializing `Foo<T>::setValue` without naming `Bar` and `Baz`, because there could be dozens of such classes.

```
class Bar
{
public:
    enum TYPE{ ONE , TWO };
};

class Baz
{
public:
    enum TYPE{ SIX , TEN };
};

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    void setValue(){} // Need a different setValue if T is a class enum

private:
    T m_value;
};


int main()
{
    Foo<int> f1;
    Foo<Bar::TYPE> f2;
    Foo<Baz::TYPE> f3; 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question - what do you want it to do if the type is an enum? You can use `enable_if` with [`is_enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982983.aspx)

Comment: @awoodland I'll take a look at `is_enum`. I want a different `Foo<T>::setValue` if `T` is a class enum (called TYPE).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with something like:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    void setValue() {
      setValueImpl<T>();
    }
private:
    template <class X>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<X>::value, void>::type
    setValueImpl() { std::cout << "Is enum" << std::endl; }

    template <class X>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_enum<X>::value, void>::type
    setValueImpl() { std::cout << "Not enum" << std::endl; } 

    T m_value;
};
```

Where `enable_if` picks which version to use based on the `is_enum` type trait.

The example used C++11 `enable_if` and `is_enum` but boost has similar for pre-C++11 also.

Comment: It sort of works bit does not discriminate between enums. I guess I've got to write a trait that'll do that.

Comment: @Olumide Hang on so you want `Bar::TYPE` and `Baz::TYPE` to be special cases but everything else to be the default? There's a far easier solution to that if it's what you're looking for. But you'll have to name the types somewhere. You can't discriminate between enums and not name them.

Comment: I was considering naming them in a trait.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Bar
{
public:
    enum TYPE{ ONE , TWO };
};

class Baz
{
public:
    enum TYPE{ SIX , TEN };
};

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename C> void setValue(const C &m_value, ...) 
    {
        std::cout << "normal" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename C> void setValue(const C &m_value, typename C::TYPE fake = C::TYPE()) 
    {
        std::cout << "TYPE'ed" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    T m_value;
};


int main()
{
    Foo<int> f1;
    Foo<Bar> f2;
    Foo<Baz> f3; 

    f1.setValue(1);
    f2.setValue(Bar());
    f3.setValue(Baz());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Didn't realize I could write `Bar::TYPE()`