# Can we specialize a enum (type) member of a class template?

Tags: c++, enums

[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) claims that, among other things, you can specialize a

> 7. member enumeration of a class template

Since no examples were provided, I attempted to guess how to do that.

I ended up with following:

```
template <typename T> struct A
{
    enum E : int;
};

template <> enum A<int>::E : int {a,b,c};
```

Clang (8.0.0 with `-std=c++17 -pedantic-errors`) compiles it.

GCC (9.1 with `-std=c++17 -pedantic-errors`) rejects the code with

```
error: template specialization of 'enum A<int>::E' not allowed by ISO C++ [-Wpedantic]
```

MSVC (v19.20 with `/std:c++latest` also rejects the code with

```
error C3113: an 'enum' cannot be a template
```

<kbd>[Try it on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5AUwBbAA7NZAag4BmAMIEAngswsmczCoAqG7CsEFiI5ARUBBDgAZnAdj5uVPlQZFyKpYgKngsBBpeHgAika7ObrKKyiYamhZ%2BLAFOaWER6tggIMGh4WqeTKQARqSc7rHqPFIAlIzSAKxSpCzSLl2o0um8/Fai4qlc6rRdBL0trQDWIFwAnAB06gBsXLQAHCsu7QAs7lyb6u5tUkddPVJ9pANSXYIgLqSz9y2kcLAwiChUIo8AxMGQKBA0MDQcQUMw2LsXO8AGYg2TEV4QKpzaphJjEHTSaa1IHGcIAeRYDEJX1IWDkrGAoJx%2BGImHseAAbphXrTMAAPdkiWRErp5TAMHEMPBVYj4nSaDCSKTEmx4ORzVrw9j8fiMGWvSCtVAKAh4VAsXkAWms6A00U4w14tHcKit%2BnQrDNyCtYOIJEELzGEjoWo6txxT35u02Vs2RxUyG1Kl2axcaZUEFwhBIakm9BUiuhYLzU2ahd1vBmmtaCEwTCwsIgixAR3W7hcux27Xcp1oSJWu3aVxupA17XedweTxebw%2Bmp%2B/wgSFEBAUwvIlChChBYLopEw%2BCIsPoAHc5QpRWGpJ1upHpNwpipT4QECpo7H44nk6n0w9Pn0zS1vWjaUNeo7jpO97PEIc4AfMpBLJMaa0CsRy7F2xxHEcmy7O46hXOoEa0jO85fK0vxQEuSDbru4JbkCO4wiAwArPQqIMOimLYrSVR4gSooknIZIEJS1IsvIjLMrSrLsma3K8g8ApCiKKpiuEEpSjKcoEoqWCCWqGrkYwjIoJWAjSlUhrNo8prmpa0g2gQdrqA65kum6HpengPp%2BgGQZiCGtDXreU79NIH5xgmwDIMgKjrLQmbZsepYFkWTElo%2BXDlkMfBVmRgHAQ2e42UsRxcGmqztBO5xcO05ybIcI5dJBd4kdIs7vPBFHUSAq7rgQm6QoxdHLAeR4kPu55MJeakhcR04PpMXDPq%2B74xlFKgxXFCXVuRRWgTZkrXC1IATm1i0wa8XU1ohyxHBs6i7FMKzqBcXBcIiuyEQt4Uwd1i7wJRy6AsW9HDWDICcsgCgKAA%2BpyqFw1wLhw/y8akBxXGUDxDx8YYAlqUJIliTSDz0lJyrk3gbIcgpOLKcgwrKsS4rHQ8lk6QqSoGcQ6oLtqZlOhZBrwMadkWryAD0tpC3lPApNYAXjKGVyhdB6MJnIgjQyoiPrCjSUTcQqWkIWI0wqW6g5eZe2FaQdbFU2LbIZ9SIuG97TqO0g64QRx0QWdUHtVdcELsDK7CgNQ20cxBGHjmJ6kNNs3TPNF1/Y%2B6irQQb6ayo2u6/rawo3bCGO4d4GnedYWPB1sE3ftd2u4iSKe97vvPT9Gd1/9t3HVwp39sHl1l0BpDchi9mtkAA%3D)</kbd>

Did I specialize the enum correctly? If not, now do I do that?

Comment: This Q/A might help provide some insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552255/specializing-member-template-for-enum-type-arguments

Comment: GCC fails also for the related case where specialization is performed on the class template rather than a member or it, but MSVC manages that variation: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9p1lmn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are examples in [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#6)([temp.expl.spec]/6) that suggest what you have is correct. The one there is:

```
template<> enum A<int>::E : int { eint };           // OK
```

Seems like a gcc bug.

Comment: There is a bug report: [bug 61491](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61491)

Comment: For reference: [How to disable GCC warnings for a few lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560/how-to-disable-gcc-warnings-for-a-few-lines-of-code) (also applies for C++)